# How to install googleVis into Anaconda R for windows

Tags: python, r, package

Anaconda is a scientific python distro that can be augmented by installing a package for using the statistical functions of R

```
>conda install -c r r-essentials
```

However, I also need to use googleVIS, the R interface to Google Charts API.

The recommended solution is this:

```
conda install -c gusdunn r-googlevis=0.5.10
```

But it does not exist for windows, only for linux and OSX.

```
anaconda search -t conda r-googlevis
```

reveals

```
Packages:
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
     bioconda/r-googlevis      |   0.5.10 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64
                                          : R interface to Google Charts API, allowing users to create interactive charts based on data frames. Charts  are displayed locally via the R HTTP help server. A modern browser with Internet connection is required and for some charts a Flash player. The data remains local and is not uploaded to Google.
     gusdunn/r-googlevis       |   0.5.10 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64
                                          : R interface to Google Charts API, allowing users to create interactive charts based on data frames. Charts  are displayed locally via the R HTTP help server. A modern browser with Internet connection is required and for some charts a Flash player. The data remains local and is not uploaded to Google.
Found 2 packages
```

I found a windows binary for googleVIS [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/):

but I do not know how to get it 'into' anaconda. Can someone  shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

well i fired up jupyter notebook (and of course my anaconda had the r essentials installed). Then i typed into a cell the usual thing I would type in R console:

```
install.packages('googleVis')
```

and it told me to stop trying to use cran without selecting a mirror. so then i did this

```
options(repos=structure(c(CRAN="https://cloud.r-project.org/")))
install.packages('googleVis')
```

Now it seems to work. 
I can even quit jupyter and restart a whole new instance of it and googleVIS works.

Answer (score -2):

I found a "googleVis" package on CRAN.  Try this from R:

```
install.packages('googleVis')
```

Edit: You can install packages directly from within Jupyter Notebook (see the other answer posted here for details) or start R in console mode from within your Anaconda installation (usually C:\Anaconda3\scripts\R.exe) and use the intsall.packages command from there.

Comment: I know I can install googleVIS into an R environment like that. But I need to use that R package within Anaconda Python! Then I can have a jupyter notebook that allows R and python. See the next one-line comment for installing R into python

Comment: That's how I install R packages to be used in Jupyter notebook, so maybe I'm missing something.  Then again, in Jupyter I'm only using either Python or R, not both together.

Comment: Good find with options(repos).  Previously to install a package into my jupyter installation I'd have to drop to command line and fire up R in console mode.  Nice to see you can install packages from with jupyter.